# Enabled users section in Symfony Debug Toolbar

Tags: php, symfony, debugging, silex

I need the users section of the symfony toolbar:

[image]

```
http://symfony.com/doc/master/security.html
```

Because I don't have it in mine...

[image]

What should I change ?

Answer (score 0):

Check if security service provider is registered. Register it if not.

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider(), [...]);
```

Also security section require symfony bundle `symfony/security-bundle`.

```
composer require symfony/security-bundle
```

Comment: SecurityServiceProvider is register, with all my confirguration. Everythink is working. Users can register themself and login in, but the toolbar doesn't have the user icon...

Comment: and `symfony/security-bundle` is installed?

Comment: run this command in the root of your project `composer require symfony/security-bundle`

Comment: I have the line "symfony/security": "~2.8|3.0.*", in my composer.json yes.

Comment: "symfony/security" <> "symfony/security-bundle" :)

Comment: But I use Silex, can I use bundle on it ?

Comment: Some classes from bundle